# class object does not print

Tags: python, class

My class object will not print in Python. Here is my code:

```
import random

suits = ("Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs")
ranks = ("Two","Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace")
values = {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10,
         'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}

playing = True

class Card:

    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + " of " + self.suit

class Deck:

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []  # start with an empty list
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit,rank))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.deck

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal(self):
        pass

test_deck = Deck()
#len(test_deck.deck)
print(test_deck)
```

The very last line of this code `print(test_deck)` gives me the following error and I do not know why because I am following similar examples that use `__str__` to print a class object:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 test_deck = Deck()
      2 len(test_deck.deck)
----> 3 print(test_deck)

TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type list)
```

I am not sure why I can't print the list? Even though I used `return`

Comment: Did you declare `Card` two times instead of declaring `Card` and `Deck`?

Comment: Try replacing `return self.deck` by `return str(self.deck)`

Comment: @JatinBansal is right, the `__str__` method needs to return a string. Here, it returns a list, therefore, it cannot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__str__` method must return string format

You may rewrite it like

```py
def __str__(self):
    return ", ".join([str(card) for card in self.deck])
```

So it will print something like this

```
Two of Hearts, Five of Diamonds
```

Or if you want to explicitly show that it is a list structure, just return `str(self.deck)`

So it will print something like this

```
"[<__main__.Card object at 0x7f8ad5a1e190>, <__main__.Card object at 0x7f8ad5a1e190>]"
```